# How to get values of list dictionary and append it to a string?

Tags: python-3.x

So here's what I'm working with. I have a list of dictionary call mugshots.

```
mugshots = [{'path': '/leds/files/2021/1000000578', 'name': 'IN202100005_F.jpg'}, {'path': '/leds/files/2021/1000000579', 'name': 'IN202100005_L.jpg'}]
```

I need to get just the value of the path and name and append it to a string. So I need a for loop and an empty string?

```
empty_string = ""
for mugshot in mugshots:
    for key, value in mugshot.items():
        empty_string= empty_string.join(value)
```

If I do this a get I/I/leds/files/2021/1000000578N/leds/files/2021/10000005782 which isn't what I want. I need to get /leds/files/2021/1000000578IN202100005_F.jpg but with maybe a separator in between /leds/files/2021/1000000578_IN202100005_F.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
mugshots = [
    {'path': '/leds/files/2021/1000000578', 'name': 'IN202100005_F.jpg'},
    {'path': '/leds/files/2021/1000000579', 'name': 'IN202100005_L.jpg'}
]
    
print(['/'.join(mugshot.values()) for mugshot in mugshots])
# Outputs ['/leds/files/2021/1000000578/IN202100005_F.jpg', '/leds/files/2021/1000000579/IN202100005_L.jpg']
```

Or, if you have more entries besides "path" and "name":

```
print(['/'.join((mugshot['path'], mugshot['name'])) for mugshot in mugshots])
# Outputs ['/leds/files/2021/1000000578/IN202100005_F.jpg', '/leds/files/2021/1000000579/IN202100005_L.jpg']
```